# Can't render items using FlatList while data is fetched by mapping from Strapi

Tags: react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to show data in frontend using FlatList. The data is fetched from Strapi using apisauce and I'm mapping the data in resp. Then I updated the value of my function slider by the value of resp. Logging the same, I get the data as I want. But when I try to show it using FlatList it isn't working.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import GlobalApi from '../Shared/GlobalApi'


const slider = () => {

  //Hooks
  const [slider, setSlider] = useState([{}]); //addings state to functional component
  useEffect(()=>{//hook for fetching data
    getSlider()
  },[])//empty sq bracket for one time rendering

  const getSlider =  async ()=>{

    const result = ((await GlobalApi.getSlider()).data);
    //console.log(result);

    const resp = result.data.map((item)=>({ //analaogous to return()
      id: item.id,
      title: item.attributes.title,
      description: item.attributes.description,
      price: item.attributes.price,
      image: item.attributes.image.data[0].attributes.url}
      )) 
    console.log(resp);
    setSlider(resp) //updating slider value with resp
  }


  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList data={slider} renderItem={(item)=>(
      <View>
          <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          <Image style={styles.imageCard} source={{uri: item.image}}/>
         
      </View>
      )} keyExtractor={(item)=>item.id}/>
    </View>
  )
}

export default slider;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageCard:{
    height: 100,
    width: 100 
  }
})
```

In console

```
[{"description": "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ", "id": 1, "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dh0tn7tyj/image/upload/v1702538045/apsc_4898c47756.png", "price": "5000", "title": "APSC"}, {"description": "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ", "id": 2, "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dh0tn7tyj/image/upload/v1702538060/upsc_8b3334ea87.jpg", "price": "5000", "title": "UPSC"}, {"description": "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ", "id": 3, "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dh0tn7tyj/image/upload/v1702538062/ssc_ef98527733.jpg", "price": "5000", "title": "SSC"}]
```

What I'm doing wrong?